# RxJava convert byte array to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Sorry for my english. Now i learning rxJava 1 and try convert byte[] to Bitmap and set it to imageview. But it work slowly. Do i right work whith rxJava? ps: i chek and asynkTask work fater than rxJava, how it possible?

```
Observable.just(data)
                .map(new Func1<byte[], Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap call(byte[] bytes) {
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                        options.inDither = true;
                        options.inMutable = true;

                        Bitmap largeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap
                                , (int) ((float) largeBitmap.getWidth() / 10)
                                , (int) ((float) largeBitmap.getHeight() / 10)
                                , true);

                        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(90); // anti-clockwise by 90 degrees

                            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                        }

                        float k = (float) bitmap.getWidth() / (float) w_target;

                        if (w_target < bitmap.getWidth()) {
                            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w_target, (int) ((float) bitmap.getHeight() / k), true);
                        }

                        return createBlackAndWhite(bitmap);
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Rxjava2?

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought learn rx1 then rx2

Comment: I think this looks okay, but there's other libraries you can use to load images

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks! Can you recomend some library?

Comment: I trust you can search for Android image loading libraries. I don't have any recommendations

Comment: The answer of @lelloman is true as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

invert the schedulers to

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

the thread you observe on is the one in which `imageView.setBitmap()` will be called, subscribeOn on the other hand will set the thread for the bitmap manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the Scheduler used to handle the process , instead of `Schedulers.io()` try `Schedulers.computation()` at least for some of your calcul.

According to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/Schedulers.html)

> **computation()**: Creates and returns a Scheduler intended for
> computational work. This can be used for event-loops, processing
> callbacks and other computational work. Do not perform IO-bound work
> on this scheduler. Use Schedulers.io() instead.
>
> **io()**: Creates and
> returns a Scheduler intended for IO-bound work. The implementation is
> backed by an Executor thread-pool that will grow as needed. This can
> be used for asynchronously performing blocking IO. Do not perform
> computational work on this scheduler. Use Schedulers.computation()
> instead.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.